# Can someone point me to a webservice URI naming convention?

Tags: web-services, uri, standards, conventions

For example, create an object, updating an object, retrieving an object by ID, retrieving an object by name.

```
POST to: /object/create
POST to: /object/update
GET to: /object/getById?id={0}
GET to: /object/getByName?name={0}
```

Or is there a convention of maybe `/object/create/create` or similar?

I'm trying to create a uniform style of webservice.

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Representational_state_transfer

Comment: Indeed I want to follow rest, it's the little details though like wanting to get items by ID or by Name, which means you can't simply do a GET to the same url - also which parts are done by parameter and which are done as part of the address, eg. `object/3/` or `object/?id=3` or similar. I'm unsure.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are many ways to model URIs, You will get a lot of confusing references on web, not that they are wrong but most of them are correct in their own context.

http://soaprobe.blogspot.co.uk/2012/10/soa-rest-service-naming-guideline.html

http://architects.dzone.com/news/common-rest-design-pattern

In your example may be you can model it this way.

**POST to: /object** - this will create the object

**PUT to: /object** -- this will update the object

**GET to: /object?id={0}** -- this will GET the object by id

**GET to: /object?name={0}** -- this will update the object by name

Comment: That looks good, what would you do if you wanted to POST many objects at the same time, for example you were maintaining a dictionary and you wanted to be able to create/update a single word, but also post an array of words as a batch job? POST to: /objects maybe?

Comment: Collection of Resource is a separate Resource by itself :) so /objects is fine. That means when you do a get on Objects ideally you want to see the complete Object LIST, you can do index based GET etc, All the goodness of REST.